# Android Manifest is severely corrupted! How do I fix it?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest

I have no idea what happened to my Android Manifest file. It says all sorts of weird stuff and weird characters.

It wouldn't let me paste as code so here it is:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4hO_4k1yMgUTVJWSXRNalZCQmc/view?usp=sharing

Can I fix this one? Do I need to make a new one? If so, how?

Comment: Yes buddy, its got corrupted and you are lucky your other code files are still good, you will need to create new one unless you can check in your IDE (Eclipse,Studio) for local backup and found any local backedup file.

Comment: Thanks! How do I create a new manifest file? Also, how could it have become corrupted?

Comment: First of all try to right click on your project and Fine option LOCAL HISTORY :-> SHOW HISTORY and in there try to find if it has any local copy saved of your manifest. 

It happens with many reasons, some time you closed the studio not properly, virus, electricity cut out, I have been a victim too. You can just delete that file and put new. That's all fine.

Comment: I tried the local history thing and it is grayed out so I guess I will need to recreate the file. Can I regenerate it automatically or how else do I recreate the file?

Comment: This looks like a compiled XML from the .apk.

Comment: You can do create new manifest file by `right click project - new - other - manifest file`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea what happened to it but it was corrupted and there was no backup. I ended up just creating a new one

Answer (score 2):

right click on manifest file then click on show in explorer then you can find the original code of your manifest file copy all of the code from your file then paste it in your manifest.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @MKJParekh. Look for local backup in eclipse. Right click in opened manifest file and click on 'compare with' then select local history.
[image]

[image]

Comment: It has no local history

Comment: What's the encoding enabled?

Answer (score 0):

When you do a build in Eclipse (on Linux anyway, not sure about Windows), a copy of your *AndroidManifest.xml* gets copied into the *bin* folder along with the APK. Have a look in there and if you are lucky the previous version will still be in there. I know you're using Android Studio but give it a try anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Faced similar problem, looks like when Android studio is not closed properly it corrupts the files. I checked local history but the required file was not there.
I was able to find auto generated AndroidManifest.xml from path 'app\build\intermediates\bundle_manifest\debug\processDebugManifest\bundle-manifest'
Need to modify it. It worked.

Comment: Interesting, what edits did you make on the file to make it work?

Comment: I remove all the auto generated items from the manifest file.

Answer (score -1):

I think you have to open the Android manifest as XML file.

Follow the instruction : Right click on the manifest file and open with xml.
I guess it will solve your issue.

Comment: That wouldn't account for the wierd characters.

Comment: There is no "open with xml" or even "open with..." when I right click!

Comment: Check this screenshot: 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwbBxeGJ1gNkd1F2eUI4YnVzcHc/view?usp=sharing